# How to wrap label text in R?

Tags: r

I'm working on a horizontal barplot with survey data. The labels for the y axis will be questions from the survey. The questions are rather long, and therefore I need to wrap the text of each question so that it appears on 2-3 lines. Can someone share how to most simply do this in base R?

```
counts <- c(5, 4.9, 4.4, 4.8, 4.9, 5.0, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9)

barplot(counts, col=c("deepskyblue2"), border = NA,  
        family="Arial", horiz = T, xlim = range(0,6))
```

I need the labels for each to wrap across 2-3 lines.

Comment: Two possibilities. Use `\n` to add a break line or make a smaller text in a new vector.

Comment: does this do the trick: http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2008/09/fitting-text-under-plot.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very raw solution and not completely base R:

```
counts <- c(5, 4.9, 4.4, 4.8, 4.9, 5.0, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9)
library(stringr) # for the function str_wrap()
library(magrittr) # just for the pipe %>%, not strictly necessary
names(counts) <- c(
  "I'm working on a horizontal",
  "barplot with survey data.",
  "The labels for the y axis",
  "will be questions from the survey.",
  "The questions are rather long, and",
  "therefore I need to wrap the text",
  "of each question so that it appears",
  "on 2-3 lines. Can someone share",
  "how to most simply do this in base R?") %>% str_wrap(width = 20)

par(mai=c(1,2,1,1)) # make space for the label
barplot(counts, col=c("deepskyblue2"), border = NA, family="Arial", horiz = T, xlim = range(0,6), las = 2)
```

[image]

PS. if base R is a strict requirement you should be able to code up something similar to `str_wrap()`.

**EDIT**

You could define your own function based on `strwrap()` from base R and drop the `stringr` dependency:

```
our_strwrap <- function(x) lapply(strwrap(x, width = 20, simplify= FALSE), paste, collapse = "\n")
```

Comment: There is a `strwrap` function in base R; could you use that?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, very useful discovery!